# Highlight the lowest value

Tags: jquery

after a mysql query i display this code

```
<div id="id1" style="border:1px solid red;" data-distance="31.5">
<div id="id2" style="border:1px solid red;" data-distance="1.9">
```

the number of div, and the value of "data-distance" outputed can be different depending on mysql result.

What i want is to change style from "border:1px solid red" to "border:1px solid green" for the div wich have the lowest value for "data-distance".

In the exemple above it will be

```
<div id="id1" style="border:1px solid red;" data-distance="31.5">
<div id="id2" style="border:1px solid green;" data-distance="1.9">
```

Comment: What happens if more than one div has the same, lowest value?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution:

```
$($("[data-distance]").get().sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.getAttribute("data-distance") - b.getAttribute("data-distance");
})[0]).css("border-color", "green");
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CrCZR/

Comment: This fails if multiple divs has min value

Comment: @AshirvadSingh It is not specified in the question if there is a need to highlight all mins or the first one only.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to set up some sort of loop.

For example, using your model:

```
var minvalue = 100000; // an arbitrary number.  Should be larger than the probable min element
var $minElement = null;

$('div[data-distance]').css('border-color','red');
$('div[data-distance]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('distance') < minvalue) {
    minvalue = $(this).data('distance');
    $minElement = $(this);
  }
});

$minElement.css('border-color','green');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bhoover10001/2KG6D/

Answer (score 0):

```
var minRes = -1;
var minObj = null;
$('div[data-distance]').each(function(){
    var val = parseFloat($(this).data('distance'));
    if(val < minRes || minRes < 0){
        minRes = val;
        minObj = this;
    }
});
$(minObj).css('border', '1px solid green');
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method:

```
var lowest = {id: '',val: Number.MAX_VALUE};
$('div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('distance') < lowest.val) {
        lowest.id = $(this).attr('id');
        lowest.val = $(this).data('distance');
    }
});
$('#'+lowest.id).css('borderColor','green');​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2TmEh/)**

Answer (score 0):

YOur code will look like this:

```
var arrayOfdistance=new Array(); //defining a Arrar Object
$('div').each(function(){arrayOfdistance.push($(this).attr('data-distance'))});  //Pushed all the distance in array object                     

var minValue= Math.min.apply(null, arrayOfdistance);      //got the min of all             
                         $('div[data-distance="'+minValue+'"]').attr('style','border:1px solid green');// applied css to all containing min value​
```

Your working FIDDLE

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pZUYr/)

Answer (score 0):

This will change the style of all items that has the lowest value:

```
$('[data-distance="'+$('div').map(function(){return parseFloat($(this).data('distance'));}).sort()[0]+'"]').css('border-color','green');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/YBtgV/